# Object keep showing password I am trying to hide it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, passwords

So I am trying to hide the password object from showing. Here's my code, I am using bcrypt to ash the password. I am hiding the return objectBut I am not getting my expected results. What am I doing wrong, please help. Greatly appreciate it. 
Thanks.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var User = require('../Models/User.js')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


router.get('/:resource', function(req, res, next){
  var resource = req.params.resource

  if (resource == 'user'){
    User.find(null, function(err, users){
      if(err) {
        res.json({
          confimration: 'error',
          message: err
        })
        return
      }

        res.json({
          confimration: 'success',
          message: users
        })
        return
    })
  }
})

router.post('/:resource', function(req, res, next){
  var resource = req.params.resource
  var data = req.body
  var password = data.password
  var hashed = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10)
  data['password'] = hashed

  if(resource == "user") {
    User.create(data, function(err, user){
      if(err){
        res.json({
          confirmation: 'fail',
          message: err
        })
        return
      }
      res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        result: user
      })
      return
    })
  }
})

    module.exports = router



   var mongoose = require('mongoose')

    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      firstName: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, default: ''},
      lastName: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, default: ''},
      email: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, default: ''},
      city: {type: String, default: ''},
      password: {type: String, default: ''},
      timestamp: {type:Date, default: Date.now}
    })

    UserSchema.methods.summary = function() {
      var summary = {
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        timestamp: this.timestamp,
        id: this._id,
        city: this.city
      }
      return summary
    }

    module.exports = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema)

{
_id: "57f460235805b52762605df2",
__v: 0,
timestamp: "2016-10-05T02:06:27.829Z",
password: "$2a$10$DIHrMO8WcRmOkIVj93SSQ.LFe5vPYH6R3xrfsSuql.v2jfU2mcO.C",
city: "new york",
email: "4",
lastName: "4",
firstName: "4"
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to hide your password from?

Comment: I want to return everything except the password. 
{
_id: "57f460235805b52762605df2",
__v: 0,
timestamp: "2016-10-05T02:06:27.829Z",
city: "new york",
email: "4",
lastName: "4",
firstName: "4"
}

Comment: Where are using your summary method? I don't Even think that matters. because If you're talking about hiding the password when you respond to the post request your sending the whole document you just saved. Your not filtering anything.

Comment: Yes Jack. How can I hide it? also doing get request too.

Comment: just for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-filter-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the `router.get` you could use a projection field. I don't know why you have null. but this `find` searches for all the docs in users collection and excludes the password field for each doc returned. does this help with the `router.get`?

```
  if (resource == 'user'){
    User.find({},{password: 0}, function(err, users){
      if(err) {
        res.json({
          confimration: 'error',
          message: err
        })
        return
      }

        res.json({
          confimration: 'success',
          message: users
        })
        return
    })
  }
```